# Check constraint with condition

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, constraints, ddl

I'm wondering if this condition can be done by a check constraint or do I need to create a trigger.

Condition : if student admited date is not null then exam mark is null

**Remark: Constaint case OR Trigger**

**What I tried :**

```
ALTER TABLE ADMITED_TABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT AAAA CHECK
 ( CASE  WHEN  DATEADMITED IS NOT NULL THEN MARK NULL END);
```

**Error:**

```
ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"
```

Comment: I correct the missing end

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A check constraints takes a boolean condition, so you'd have to frame this logic in a form of such a condition:

```
ALTER TABLE ADMITED_TABLE
ADD CONSTRAINT AAAA CHECK
(dateadmited IS NULL OR mark IS NULL);
```

Comment: It return an error : cannot validate (SYSTEM.AAAA ) - check constraint violated

Comment: @DavidEdgar This means you have data that isn't consistent with the requirement. You should either fix it, or declare the constraint as initially deferred.

Comment: In my table ADMITED_TABLE the two columns are like this (dateadmited DATE,  MARK INTEGER ). There is no NOT NULL OR NULL when table is created.

Comment: Is that mean that my new check is failling beacause other checks ??

Comment: @DavidEdgar It means that there is at least one row in your table that does not match the constraint condition; for example there can be a row wirh `dateadmited` not `null` and `mark` not `null`

Comment: @Mureinik - Why so complicated? Simpler: `(dateadmitted is null or mark is null)`

Comment: So in this case, does  novalidate resolve my problem. I will try.

Comment: @DavidEdgar That will solve your problem, but only partially. If you have rows in the table already, where both values are non-NULL, they will continue to exist in the table; only new rows will be subject to the constraint (and modifications to existing rows). What you - or your business - will choose to do with the existing rows that violate the constraint is a separate business decision (and possibly more work for you and your team).

Comment: @mathguy that would allow both `dateadmitted` and `mark` to be `null`. I'm not sure that that's allowed according to the OP's business logic.

Comment: @Mureinik - At least that is what the OP stated. But if your interpretation is correct, then your code isn't, anyway. The first branch of your OR allows both column values to be NULL regardless of the second branch.

Comment: @mathguy you're right, I don't know what I was thinking. Edited and fixed.

Answer (score 3):

I must be misreading David's requirement, because my solution is:

```
ALTER TABLE admitted_table
    ADD CONSTRAINT aaaa CHECK
            ( (dateadmitted IS NOT NULL
           AND mark IS NULL)
          OR dateadmitted IS NULL);
```

The following are my test cases:

```
-- Succeeds
INSERT INTO admitted_table (
           dateadmitted, mark
            )
     VALUES (SYSDATE, NULL);

-- Fails due to check constraint
INSERT INTO admitted_table (
           dateadmitted, mark
            )
     VALUES (SYSDATE, 10);

-- Succeeds
INSERT INTO admitted_table (
           dateadmitted, mark
            )
     VALUES (NULL, 99);
```

Answer (score 1):

From the description in the question it appears that what you want is a trigger, not a constraint. A constraint lets you verify that values in a table are as you expect them to be; however, a constraint cannot change the value of a column. So if you're just trying to verify that the values supplied match your rules a CHECK constraint is sufficient. If you want to (potentially) change the value of the MARK column you'll need to use a trigger, such as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE ADMITED_TABLE_BIU
  BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON ADMITED_TABLE
  FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  IF :NEW.DATEADMITED IS NOT NULL THEN
    :NEW.MARK := NULL;
  END IF;
END ADMITED_TABLE_BIU;
```

Best of luck.